# How to create block with specific integer with C language

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

Two-dimensional integer array (5x5) with only `0` and `1` values.

There are:

- 8 neighbours for any element in the middle of the matrix.
- 5 neighbours for the elements on the border (row=0, column=0, row=4 or column=4) of the matrix
- 3 neighbours for the elements on the corner of the matrix.

Block contains connected `1`.

In  this homework, you will write a complete C program to create a 2-D (5x5) array and fill the array with random numbers (0 or 1). Program will find the number of blocks in the matrix (5x5).

Here is my question, I fill array with numbers but I can't find how to connect `1`s as block.

This is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>     
#include <time.h>       

void find(int arr[][5],int size);

int main()
{
    int arr[5][5];
    int i,j;

    srand (time(NULL));

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            arr[i][j]=rand()%2;
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    find(arr,5);


}

void find(int arr[][5],int size)
{
    int i,j,count=0;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {



        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You can traverse the matrix and when you encounter a 1, use a [flood-fill algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) to overwrite the connected ones with a new "colour". You could use -1, -2, -3 as new block markers and keep a count of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

a 'brute' force algorithm would use the facts as you laid out.

I.E.  4 checks for the corners 12 checks for the edges, 9 checks for the interior blocks

and example corner check:

```
int countOfBlocks = 0;
if( arr[0][0] && arr[0][1] && arr[1][0] && arr[1][1] ) countOfBlocks++;
...
```

The code would then take 25 lines of 'if's, similar to the above